# On Activity App Bar back pressed go to the parent activity with the fragment it was called

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-navigation

I'm having an issue that maybe is happening to other community members and I wanted to ask if somebody knows the solution. I have an app with these Two activities (MainActivity, UserProfileActivity).

The MainActivity contains a NavigationDrawer that navigates through fragments. So here it's the problem. While navigating in the second fragment and pressing a button in that fragment. It opens the UserProfileActivity (child of MainActivity) with the app bar generated by being a child. When you press that back button of this new Activity it should get back to MainActivity (parent) in the fragment that we were when we called this new Activity. But not, it's getting back to the MainActivity but with the home fragment loaded. Not the one we called previously.

Does anybody know how to solve that problem? Here I leave the code of the intent I do from the fragment:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, UserProfileActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("userId", message.getUserId());
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: When changing fragment did you add the second fragment to backstack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason behind this behavior:**

If you set the value of `android:parentActivityName` in your manifest.xml, by default pressing navigation button will create a new instance of the parent activity every time rather than popping it out from the activity backstack, so you're seeing the home fragment.

**Workaround**

At first, remove `android:parentActivityName` from manifest.xml. In onCreate method of your ChildActivity, put `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` if you haven't already. Then override `onSupportNavigateUp()` of your ChildActivity, and put `finish()`.

ChildActivity.java:

```
public class ChildActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        finish();
        return super().onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked fine, is this workaround the programmatically way?

Comment: No, it is not the actual way of parent-child relationship of Activities. In this way when you launch your ChildActivity directly from anywhere outside of your app (eg. from notification, homescreen widget etc.), pressing back button will exit your app, not navigate to the ParentActivity. So if you didn't need to launch it from outside and navigate back to ParentActivity, then it just works fine.